# Lessen redundant calls/lookups from a class or ID

Tags: jquery

Apologies for the bad title or question. But to make it easier understand I have a code here that calls the header multiple times for example. The variable below specifies the element to clone which is `#header a[href=$="programs"]`. The ID `#header` is called multiple times in parts of my code. Is there a way to call it once and insert it in parts of my code instead of adding it manually. I'm still new to javascript.

I hope I managed to explain it well despite my lack of understanding on programming.

```
    var programsMenu = [];
        programsMenu.push($('#header a[href$="/programs"]').clone());
        programsMenu.push($('#header a[href$="/programs"]').next().clone());


    var degreesMenu = [];
        programsMenu.push($('#header a[href$="/programs"]').clone());
        degreesMenu.push($('#header a[href$="/degree-programs"]').clone());
        degreesMenu.push($('#header a[href$="/degree-programs"]').next().clone());
```

---

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';


    var footerNavigation = {
        init : function() {

            var programsMenu = [];
                programsMenu.push($('#header a[href$="/programs"]').clone());
                programsMenu.push($('#header a[href$="/programs"]').next().clone());


            var degreesMenu = [];
                programsMenu.push($('#header a[href$="/programs"]').clone());
                degreesMenu.push($('#header a[href$="/degree-programs"]').clone());
                degreesMenu.push($('#header a[href$="/degree-programs"]').next().clone());

            $('#footer .programs-menu .degree').append(degreesMenu);

            var nonDegreeMenu = [];
                nonDegreeMenu.push($('#header a[href$="/executive-education-programs"]').clone());
                nonDegreeMenu.push($('#header a[href$="/development-education-programs"]').clone());
                nonDegreeMenu.push($('#header a[href$="/program-schedules"]').clone());

            $('#footer .programs-menu .non-degree').append(nonDegreeMenu);

            var schoolMenu = [];
                schoolMenu.push($('#header a[href$="/schools"]').clone());
                schoolMenu.push($('#header a[href$="/schools"]').next().clone());

                $('#footer .schools-faculty-menu .schools').append(schoolMenu);


            var facultyMenu = [];
                facultyMenu.push($('#header a[href$="/faculty-and-staff"]').clone());
                facultyMenu.push($('#header a[href$="/faculty-and-staff"]').next().clone());

                 $('#footer .schools-faculty-menu .faculty').append(facultyMenu);

            // var researchMenu = [];
            //     researchMenu.push($('a[href$="/research-centers"]').clone());
            //     researchMenu.push($('a[href$="/research-centers"]').next().clone());

            var researchCenters  = $('#header a[href$="/research-centers"]').next().clone(),
                centersList      = $('li', researchCenters),
                research         = $('#footer .research-centers-menu .research'),
                publications     = $('#footer .research-centers-menu .publications'),
                publicationsMenu = $('<ul class="menu" />').appendTo(publications),
                researchMenu     = $('<ul class="menu" />').appendTo(research),
                centers          = centersList.slice(0, 6),
                resources        = centersList.slice(6);

            //Store Research anchor and AIM Research Centers 
            var aimResearchCenters = [];
                aimResearchCenters.push($('#header a[href$="/research-centers"]').clone());
                aimResearchCenters.push($(researchMenu.append(centers)));

            //Append aimResearch array
            $('#footer .research-centers-menu .research').append(aimResearchCenters);

            publicationsMenu.append(resources);


            /*
            $('#footer .research-centers-menu .research').append(centers);
            $('#footer .research-centers-menu .publications').append(resources);
            */


            var aboutMenu = [];
                aboutMenu.push($('a[href$="/about-us"]').clone());
                aboutMenu.push($('a[href$="/about-us"]').next().clone());

            $('#footer .about-menu .about').append(aboutMenu);


            //Duplicate Breadcrumns on header and insert it on footer
            var breadcrumbs = $('.region-breadcrumb').clone();
            $('.region-breadcrumb').clone().insertAfter('#footer .footer-head');
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        footerNavigation.init();
    })

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable to carry jQuery elements.

This not only enable to shorten the code and make more it readable...
It also reduces the jQuery lookups over the document to find the elements, making your code more efficient.

Like:

```
var programs = $('#header a[href$="/programs"]');
var degrees = $('#header a[href$="/degree-programs"]');
var schools = $('#header a[href$="/schools"]');

// and so on...
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight, although I have thought about using variables instead I was thinking more a function i guess. But thank you for this

Comment: You have to define the elements you wish to target. And that is the way you can do it once... Then use it multiple times. There no no other way I know.